# Swing flow layout properties

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

I've been playing around with the card layout demo:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/CardLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/CardLayoutDemo.java

I want to build a gui like this but I'm struggling with the flow layout, I found other properties to help space things as desired but I can't get them to work with this example. Can someone please show me how to apply the below properties to the flow layout from the demo:

```
public FlowLayout(int alignment, int horizontalGap, int verticalGap)
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Just control over the spacing between elements and the alignment of them. I was hoping I could set a uniform gap between everything as it's all stacked close together.

Comment: @mao The parameter name says what you want. If you want to align elements in same width, use GridLayout.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, you just need to experiment...

[image]

```
public class TestFlow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFlow();
    }

    public TestFlow() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            add(createPane(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
            add(createPane(FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 15));
            add(createPane(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 20, 20));
            add(createPane(FlowLayout.LEADING, 0, 0));
            add(createPane(FlowLayout.TRAILING, 5, 5));
        }

        protected JPanel createPane(int alignment, int hGap, int vGap) {

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(alignment, hGap, vGap));
            panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
            panel.add(new JLabel("Left"));
            panel.add(new JLabel("Middle"));
            panel.add(new JLabel("Right"));

            return panel;

        }

    }

}
```